# CNTK fastrCNN - Training Custom Images - FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning, cntk

I am trying to train fastrCNN module from CNTK library. I have made necessary changes in PARAMETERS.py file. When I ran A1_GenerateROI.py, It generated ROIs but I got following message.

```
Number of images in set train = 73
Processing image set 'train', image 0 of 73
wrote gt roidb to C:\local\CNTK-2-0-beta15-0-Windows-64bit-CPU-Only\cntk\Examples\Image\Detection\FastRCNN/proc/KYC_100/cntkFiles/train.cache_gt_roidb.pkl
Only keeping the first 100 ROIs..
wrote ss roidb to C:\local\CNTK-2-0-beta15-0-Windows-64bit-CPU-Only\cntk\Examples\Image\Detection\FastRCNN/proc/KYC_100/cntkFiles/train.cache_selective_search_roidb.pkl
Processing image set 'train', image 50 of 73
Number of images in set test = 18
Processing image set 'test', image 0 of 18
wrote gt roidb to C:\local\CNTK-2-0-beta15-0-Windows-64bit-CPU-Only\cntk\Examples\Image\Detection\FastRCNN/proc/KYC_100/cntkFiles/test.cache_gt_roidb.pkl
Only keeping the first 100 ROIs..
wrote ss roidb to C:\local\CNTK-2-0-beta15-0-Windows-64bit-CPU-Only\cntk\Examples\Image\Detection\FastRCNN/proc/KYC_100/cntkFiles/test.cache_selective_search_roidb.pkl
DONE.
```

Now when I try run A2_RunCntk.py I am gettting following error msg.

```
(cntk-py35) C:\local\CNTK-2-0-beta15-0-Windows-64bit-CPU-Only\cntk\Examples\Image\Detection\FastRCNN>python A2_RunCntk.py
--------------------------------------------------------------
2017-05-19 09:53:31
PARAMETERS: datasetName = KYC
PARAMETERS: cntk_nrRois = 100
cntk.exe configFile=C:\local\CNTK-2-0-beta15-0-Windows-64bit-CPU-Only\cntk\Examples\Image\Detection\FastRCNN/proc/KYC_100/cntkFiles/fastrcnn.cntk currentDirectory=C:\local\CNTK-2-0-beta15-0-Windows-64bit-CPU-Only\cntk\Examples\Image\Detection\FastRCNN/proc/KYC_100/cntkFiles/ NumLabels=4 NumTrainROIs=100 TrainROIDim=400 TrainROILabelDim=400 NumTestROIs=100 TestROIDim=400 TestROILabelDim=400
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A2_RunCntk.py", line 41, in <module>
    pid = subprocess.Popen(cmdStr, cwd = cntkFilesDir)
  File "c:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "c:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py35\lib\subprocess.py", line 955, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Which file is mentioned here, I am not able to figure it out and what should I do. I do not see same error when I try to run Grocery image data set.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to try to repro the problem with the latest RC2 bits. Also, can you try out with the Python examples which might be easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Set the path to CNTK.exe following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/Object-Detection-using-Fast-R-CNN#quick-guide

The tutorial further assumes that the folder where cntk.exe resides is in your PATH environment variable. (To add the folder to your PATH you can run the following command from a command line (assuming the folder where cntk.exe is on your machine is C:\src\CNTK\x64\Release): set PATH=C:\src\CNTK\x64\Release;%PATH%.)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that CNTK is properly installed in your environment.

Run `pip list` in your Python environment and check if you have CNTK module properly installed.
It should look similar to this:

[pip list in Python console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7BIR.png)

For more instructions follow this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/setup-cntk-on-your-machine